# Doctrine doesn't load associations from session correctly

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm having this behavior with Doctrine 2.1 where I'm looking for a nice 'workaround'. The problem is as follows:

I have a user Entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * 
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @Column(type="integer",nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Column(type="datetime",nullable=false)   
     */
    protected $insertDate;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserGroup", cascade={"merge"})
     */
    protected $userGroup;
}
```

And a **usergroup** entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class UserGroup extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * 
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @Column(type="integer",nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string",nullable=false)     
     */
    protected $name;   
}
```

If I instantiate a user object (doing this with Zend_Auth) and Zend_Auth puts it automatically the session.

The problem is however, that is I pull it back from the session at a next page then the data in the user class is perfectly loaded but not in the userGroup association. If I add cascade={"merge"} into the annotation in the user object the userGroup object IS loaded but the data is empty. If you dump something like:

`$user->userGroup->name`

You will get NULL back. The problem is no data of the usergroup entity is accesed before the user object is saved in the session so a empty initialized object will be returned. If I do something like:

```
echo $user->userGroup->name;
```

Before I store the user object in the session all data of the assocication userGroup is succesfully saved and won't return NULL on the next page if I try to access the $user->userGroup->name variable.

Is there a simple way to fix this? Can I manually load the userGroup object/association with a lifecycle callback @onLoad in the user class maybe? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a combination of what mjh_ca answered and a problem with your `AbstractEntity` implementation.

Since you show that you access entity fields in this fashion:

```
$user->userGroup->name;
```

I assume your `AbstractEntity` base class is using `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods instead of proper getters and setters:

```
function getUserGroup()
{
    return $this->userGroup;
}

function setUserGroup(UserGroup $userGroup)
{
    $this->userGroup = $userGroup;
}
```

You are essentially breaking lazy loading:

> "... whenever you access a public property of a proxy object that hasn’t been initialized yet the return value will be null. Doctrine cannot hook into this process and magically make the entity lazy load."

Source: [Doctrine Best Practices: Don't Use Public Properties on Entities](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/best-practices.html#don-t-use-public-properties-on-entities)

You should instead be accessing fields this way:

```
$user->getUserGroup()->getName();
```

The second part of your problem is exactly as mjh_ca wrote - `Zend_Auth` detaches your entity from the entity manager when it serializes it for storage in the session. Setting `cascade={"merge"}` on your association will not work because it is the actual entity that is detached.  You have to merge the deserialized `User` entity into the entity manager.

```
$detachedIdentity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
$identity = $em->merge($detachedIdentity);
```

The question, is how to do this cleanly. You could look into implementing a `__wakeup()` magic method for your `User` entity, but that is also against doctrine best practices...

Source: [Implementing Wakeup or Clone](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html)

Since we are talking about `Zend_Auth`, you could extend `Zend_Auth` and override the `getIdentity()` function so that it is entity aware.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork;

class My_Auth extends \Zend_Auth
{
    protected $_entityManager;

    /**
     * override otherwise self::$_instance
     * will still create an instance of Zend_Auth
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->_entityManager;
    }

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->_entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getIdentity()
    {
        $storage = $this->getStorage();

        if ($storage->isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        $identity = $storage->read();

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        if(UnitOfWork::STATE_DETACHED === $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($identity))
        {
            $identity = $em->merge($identity);
        }

        return $identity;
    }
}
```

And than add an `_init` function to your Bootstrap:

```
public function _initAuth()
{
    $this->bootstrap('doctrine');
    $em = $this->getResource('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

    $auth = My_Auth::getInstance();
    $auth->setEntityManager($em);
}
```

At this point calling `$user->getUserGroup()->getName();` should work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

When you store the entity to a session (via Zend_Auth or otherwise), the object is serialized and no longer maintained by Doctrine when subsequently retrieved and unserialized.  Try merging the entity back into the EntityManager.  See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-objects.html

Comment: I tried that but the actual problem is that the userGroup association ISN'T filled BEFORE it got serialized. This causes that merge() doesn't take affect even if you call it directly to the userGroup object itself. This problem occurs when you don't access the userGroup object before it got serialized because Doctrine loads the entity data only when it gets called. Do you get my problem? For now I have a workaround with echo $user->userGroup->name; but that isn't a nice one. I'm looking for something to manually load the userGroup entity. hope you understand.